# GET favorites/playlists sometimes returns 500

Tags: sonos

I am trying to run calls to GET households/householdId/favorites & households/householdId/playlists for multiple devices in succession in my code. The call will work sometimes and correctly return a response. But other times for the exact same call, I will get a `500 Internal Server Error`. Has anyone else seen this happen?

If I attempt to run the exact same call in postman that had initially failed through code, it works fine.

Comment: What service are you calling? It's possible you having rate limits.

Comment: Rate limits would return a 429 Too Many Requests according to their documentation. I'm calling the Sonos cloud api's.

Comment: Just a note that both favorites and playlists don't change between devices in a household. In other words, a household has a single list of favorites and a single list of playlists and all queries to any devices in that household will return the same list.

Comment: These are docs I'm going by - https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/
You can't query a device.  You have to query favorites, playlists, groups, etc within a household.  All of these relationships tie back to the household, not the device.

Comment: Hi, can you email developer-feedback@sonos.com with your household ID and a specific time when you sent the request and got an HTTP 500 response? Please include your StackOverflow username as well.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the logs for the time and householdId you provided. The requests are actually being rate limited, but the proper HTTP response code is not being returned to the client in this particular case. We will file an enhancement to improve the HTTP response code for this case.

To expand a little on the rate limiting - each of the requests your integration makes (GET groups, GET playlists, GET favorites for example) reach a device in the household, and some of these requests may take longer to process if the household has a large number of devices. Each device can only handle processing a certain number of commands at once, so if the household is being actively used (Sonos controller, voice integrations, etc), some requests may end up being rate limited.

Retrying when you receive an error is a reasonable implementation, but it won't eliminate the intermittent errors you are seeing with large active households. My recommendation would be to try to reduce the number of requests your integration is sending, if possible. For example - you can save the result of a GET groups request and subscribe to the groups namespace. That way, you can rely on receiving group change events to stay updated rather than make a GET groups request to the household so frequently.

Event subscription overview: https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/connect/

Groups subscription documentation: https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/groups/subscribe/